# Text-cursor position handling in C (under Linux)

Tags: c, linux, console, caret

I'm trying to reposition the text-cursor to top left corner of the console each frame, so the resulted square rendered at the same position

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    while(1) {
        printf("\u2554\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2557\n\u255A\u2550\u2550\u2550\u255D\n");
    }
}
```

I found that this is possible in windows by including `<windows.h>`:

```c
HANDLE hOut;
    COORD Position;
    hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    Position.X = 0;
    Position.Y = 0;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut,Position);
```

How can I do that in Ubuntu?

Comment: On POSIX systems (like Linux) I suggest you take a closer look at the ncurses library.

Comment: I will take a look, thanks @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[update] Oops, sorry, I didn't notice the "[C]" tag and my answer was only referring to shell commands.

The actual answer is to use a curses-like library, like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

For example, the function you are looking for is typically [`move()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/move).

---

Original answer:

On Unix systems, moving the cursor depends on the type of the terminal you are using.

There are libraries like `ncurses` that aim to provide functionalities that are terminal-independent. `tput` is a command that uses `ncurses` to make some terminal capabilities (like moving the cursor) available to the command line:

```
tput cup 0 0
```

will put the cursor in the (0,0) position, whatever the terminal you are using (if such a terminal allows you to move the cursor)

Answer (score 0):

Write `\033[H` to the console, and this will put the cursor in the top left corner of the terminal.

For that, the terminal must be ANSI compatible (for example, the `xterm` terminal or the linux console)

Anyway, I recommend you to use the ncurses library, which gives you many possibilities, apart of this, and in a manner that is terminal type independent (so it will run in almost any known terminal type, e.g. an hp terminal)